# Two remote repositories, different forlders

Tags: git, git-remote

I have a git repository:

Repository A:

```
config
  view1.yml
  view2.yml
public
  css/
    styles.css
  js/
    scripts.js
  index.html
```

I want add another remote repository but just tracking the contents of the public folder, example:

Repository B:

```
css/
  styles.css
js/
  scripts.js
index.html
```

how I can do that in local? with `git remote add`?

Comment: Take a look at [this related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38099643/4233593)

Answer (score 1):

If everything is under one directory that you want to export and you really want to omit everything else, you might filter the branch down with git filter-branch and then push just that resultant branch out to Repo B.

From the tip of the branch you are interested in, assuming you want to keep just changes to dir "public" and below:

```
git checkout -b nameOfPublicBranch
// Create a new branch where you want to start to filter

git filter-branch -f --subdirectory-filter public
// This filters your branch down to commits that modified public (and below)

git push repoB nameOfPublicBranch
// now export to repoB just this stuff that you wanted on your branch nameOfPublicBranch

git checkout <yourOldBranchName>
// get back to your old branch
```

If you want to squash the commits down into one on branch nameOfPublicBranch, then do a rebase squash on it before you push it.

There are probably many other ways to approach this and one could be the use of submodules and there may be unintended issues with this approach (rewriting history).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [git subtree](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt). From their documentation it explains the following:

> ...Subtrees allow subprojects to be included within a subdirectory  of
>   the main project, optionally including the subproject's  entire
>   history.
>
> For example, you could include the source code for a library  as a
>   subdirectory of your application...

I would create the new bare repository somewhere (`git init --bare`) and do a  subtree `split` command to "branch off" the history of your public folder. Then I would push this information to your other repository. This example can be seen at the above linked in documentation as [Example 3](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt#L324).

```
<go to the new location> 
git init --bare  
git subtree split --prefix=lib --annotate="(split)" -b split   
git push <new-repo> split:master
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use gitignore (which tells git to ignore files and don't track them) with the following content (*not tested*):

```
*
!/css
!/js
```

If you already have files tracked, then you need to run `git rm --cached <file>` before setting up the gitignore.

If you want to learn more about gitignore, maybe you want to read [this part](https://learningpassion.wordpress.com/2016/06/17/git-tutorial-day-to-day-use-part-4-gitignore-diff-and-difftools-moving-and-removing-files/) of git tutorial.