# How to pull in changes from skeleton sub-repository into production super-repository

Tags: git, aurelia

I am using the [Aurelia skeleton](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation) which contains various project setups for different purposes, but it is more of a general question of how you would do something with git like discribed below.

I would like to be able to merge in the updates published in the GitHub skeleton repository to the project I am actually working on. How would you do that?

At the moment I just initialized a new local repository in the skeleton-typescript project (which I am using) and connected it to a private remote repo to push my changes. But with this setup, I am polluting the parent repository (remote pointing to aurelia-skeleton on Github) with my project-specific changes.

It would be perfect to have some kind of one-way tracking going as the aurelia-skeleton remote repository is normally only used to pull changes in.

As a second step, it would be interesting how you could create a pull request with such a setup. In this case, I would like to use the changes I made in the sub-repository to be merged into the fork of the aurelia remote...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My usual workflow is to create a dedicated branch from which to track the upstream project. You can cherry pick what you want onto that branch and create a pull request without muddying the template with your project specifics.

---

First thing, go ahead and fork `aurelia/skeleton-navigation` so you can easily issue a pull request through Github's GUI.

Clone your fork of the project with remote named `upstream` in a *new* folder called `skeleton-typescript`

```
git clone -o upstream git@github.com:YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME/skeleton-navigation.git skeleton-typescript

cd skeleton-typescript
```

Rename master branch.

```
git branch -m asmaster
```

Create a new repository for `skeleton-typescript`

**Tip:** You can do this right from the command line using [Github's API](https://developer.github.com/) with something like [`curl`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl)

```
curl --data '{"name":"skeleton-typescript"}' -u YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME https://api.github.com/user/repos
```

Add the remote.

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME/skeleton-typescript.git
```

Split the repo into a subtree ([see source code for man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt)) which will contain a new tree with all the commit history of files in the `prefix` directory.

```
git subtree split --prefix=skeleton-typescript
```

This will print out a single commit ID which is the `HEAD` of the subtree.

> 539d913a8cf9b34b644273b5cdb480359553247c

Create your master branch from that commit.

```
git checkout -b master 539d913a8cf9b34b644273b5cdb480359553247c
```

Push to and track your new repo.

```
git push -u origin master
```

## Backporting

Commit some work on `skeleton-typescript`

```
echo "notable contribution" >> file.txt
git add .
git commit -m "backport test commit"
git push origin master
```

Checkout the upstream super-project branch, and cherry-pick the subtree commits.

```
git checkout asmaster
git cherry-pick -x --strategy=subtree master
git push upstream asmaster:master
```

Now you can issue a pull request from your upstream fork `YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME/skeleton-navigation:master` branch to their `aurelia/skeleton-navigation:master` branch.

## Updating

Now there's going to be updates no doubt to your upstream's upstream (`aurelia/skeleton-navigation:master`) which will include updates to your subtree's `skeleton-typescript` folder.

Add another remote to track the original project.

```
git remote add upupstream git@github.com:aurelia/skeleton-navigation.git
```

Note that you now have 3 remotes in your local repository.

```
git remote -v
```

> ```
> origin    git@github.com:YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME/skeleton-typescript.git (fetch)
> origin    git@github.com:YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME/skeleton-typescript.git (push)
> upstream  git@github.com:YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME/skeleton-navigation.git (fetch)
> upstream  git@github.com:YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME/skeleton-navigation.git (push)
> upupstream    git@github.com:aurelia/skeleton-navigation.git (fetch)
> upupstream    git@github.com:aurelia/skeleton-navigation.git (push)
> ```

Pull down updates.

```
git checkout asmaster
git pull upupstream master
```

Split off the subtree again and grab the HEAD commit.

```
git subtree split --prefix=skeleton-typescript
```

> 095c0c9f7ed06726e9413030eca4050a969ad0af

Switch back to subproject.

```
git checkout master
```

If you have never backported changes, then a notable attribute of `git subtree split` is that you'll have the exact same hash commit history, so you can fast forward merges without rewriting history. From [the docs](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt):

> Repeated splits of exactly the same history are guaranteed to be identical (i.e. to produce the same commit ids). Because of this, if you add new commits and then re-split, the new commits will be attached as commits on top of the history you generated last time, so git merge and friends will work as expected.

```
git merge 095c0c9f7ed06726e9413030eca4050a969ad0af
```

However, if you have already backported cherry-picked updates, or any other changes to the subtree history, then you'll want to rebase changes, otherwise you'll have duplicate commits.

```
git rebase 095c0c9f7ed06726e9413030eca4050a969ad0af
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answer. This helps a lot, but I am still having some issues. I assume, with the first command i am supposed to clone the official aurelia skeleton project, so in my case it would be:
`git clone -o upstream git@github.com:aurelia/skeleton-navigation.git skeleton-typescript`

Comment: The problem is, by doing that I clone the full repository containing all the different project setups and not only the typescript one, which is ok for pull request creation etc. and tracking the changes on the template, but I don't want to have the whole repository in my private project repository.

Comment: @MannikJ ah, sorry I didn't look at the repository. You need a subtree. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Wow! I didn't even dream about such an elaborate answer. Thank you for your great effort. I will give it a try tomorrow and will surely except it when everything works fine.