# Merge remote into local subdirectory of a git project

Tags: git, git-pull

I have the following situation: Local, forked and customized git project that did not maintain the folder structure of the source.

`~/dwm/dwm/* and ~/dwm/dwmstatus/*` is the new structure of my git project.

I now wanted to patch the latest source into my local repo. I `git remote add http://git.suckless.org/dwm/` and do a pull.

What happens is that the pull ignores the subdirectories (how should it know at first) and makes a full pull into `~/dwm/*`.

Question: How can I merge from the source remote into the ~/dwm/dwm/* subfolder? 
What I tried: `git checkout HEAD dwm/` and perform a pull then. This didn't do the trick as the directory was already up to date.

Comment: If you had committed your structural modifications, this should more or less have just worked.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: I don't have any influence on the source repository. I did fork it, removed the old remote and replaced it with my github remote. The github remote is aware of my structural modifications. But the source remote is not. Or did I misunderstand your hint?

Comment: Oh, maybe I didn't follow your explanation.  You made these structural changes in a *remote*, not in your local clone?

Comment: [This might be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38097157/how-to-pull-in-changes-from-skeleton-sub-repository-into-production-super-reposi/38099643#38099643)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear from your description what sequence of actions you took.  But if your forked repo (let's call it `fork`) is strictly ahead of your original repo (let's call it `original`), then setting it as a new remote in your local repo and pulling from it should have replicated the restructuring.

Worked example:

```sh
## Create original repo ##
git init original
cd original
echo "a" > a.txt
echo "b" > b.txt
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
cd ..

## Clone the original (this is your local copy) ##
git clone original local

## Emulate fork with restructured content ##
cp -r original fork
cd fork
mkdir c d
mv a.txt c
mv b.txt d
git add .
git commit -m "Move stuff around"
cd ..

## Add the fork as a remote and pulling ##
cd local
git remote add fork ../fork
git pull fork master
```

Comment: After tinkering around with your solution for a while I see how it is supposed to work and adapted it to my needs. Thanks!